# Difference between word

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

What is difference between 'folk' and 'folks' & 'fund' and 'funds'.
Plz give examples also ,cz my grammar teacher changed folk to folks and funds to fund in some questions.

Comment: A singular, countable noun such as _difference_ should be preceded by a _determiner_ such as the indefinite or definite article, a _possessive pronoun_ such as _my, your, his, her, its, our, their, whose_, or a _demonstrative_ such as  _this_ or _that_, &c. Also, please use the best English of which you are capable when writing questions and answers at ELL. Such things as **U**, **cz** and **plz**, &c.,  may be appropriate, or even preferred, for use in social media or text messaging; but here, where no premium is placed on brevity or screen space, they are not useful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I need context, but nevertheless:

'Folk' refers to people, or a community. 'Folks' is used when talking to a group of people to directly refer to them (*That's all, folks!*).

'Fund' is a noun meaning a collection of money, such as that of a charity (World Wildlife Fund), or a verb meaning to put money towards something (fund someone's education). 'Funds' refers to the money in the collection, or money itself.